# Repeater with separated network

Tags: networking, repeater

I have ASUS AC86u. I want to share the Internet connection with my neighbour. He has the wired connection from ISP. I would like to connect to his WiFi with my router.

I know I can use the repeater mode and even broadcast a different network name in my apartment, however this mode still creates one LAN network, so the neighbour will see my printer etc.

Is it possible to connect my router to the neighbour's WiFi and create a separated network for my LAN? I cannot see such option in the router configuration.

It is not possible to connect my router to the neighbour's one with a wire.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither DD-WRT nor OpenWRT supports the AC86u. I have tried merlin, but I see no LAN configuration options when switch to repeater mode.